# What is the projection matrix of a matrix $X$ into the row space of a matrix $Y$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $X$ is a matrix and I would like to project it into the row space of another matrix $Y$.

In this this case, would the projection be:

$$
\hat{X} = XY^T(YY^T)^{-1}Y
$$

Or would it be the usual least squares format where the matrix $X$ appears on the right side instead, as in:

$$
\hat{X} = Y^T(YY^T)^{-1}YX
$$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the matrix that projects a vector onto the column space of $Y$ is given by $Y(Y^T Y)^{-1} Y^T$, we have that the matrix which projects onto the row space of $Y$ ($=$ column space of $Y^T$) is given by 
$$Y^T (Y Y^T)^{-1} Y$$
Since the matrix product $A B$ has $A$ acting upon the individual columns of $B$, the projection you're after is the second one:
$$Y^T (Y Y^T)^{-1} Y X$$

**Example**

Let $Y=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and let $X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$. This product gives:
 $$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4 \\
 2 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am a bit confused however, under the column space example, it seems that normally we would have $Y(Y^TY)^{-1}Y^TX$. But in this case the $Y^TX$ at the end is not a valid matrix multiplication. Would you know what is going on here?

Comment: I think that the issue might be the ambiguity of "project a matrix onto a subspace of $\R^n$"---do we mean project the rows or project the columns of said matrix? For the example I gave, it is meaningless to project the columns of $X$ (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) onto the column space of $Y$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) as they don't even live in the right spaces.

Comment: Probably the better way to approach this is wanting to project a collection of vectors, rather than projecting a matrix---this avoids all these ambiguities.

Comment: I see, my original intention was actually to see what it is meant to project $X$ row by row into the column space of $Y$. I am trying to understand why in this specific case of row by row projection the right answer would be $XY^T(YY^T)^{-1}YX$ (or at least I hope it is so).